# find $ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x} \sin t\,dt}{x^2 + x\sin x}$

Tags: real-analysis

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_{0}^{x} sintdt}{x^2 + xsinx}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(\int_{0}^{x} sintdt)'}{(x^2 + xsinx)'}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sinx}{2x + sinx+xcosx}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(sinx)'}{(2x + sinx+xcosx)'} $$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{cosx}{2+cosx+cosx-xsinx}=\frac{1}{4}$$

is that right??

Comment: @user502959: I'm afraid you didn't notice the O.P. applied L'Hospital's rule a second time.

Comment: yUp good job dude